# Is 身 commonly used as a measure word?

Tags: measure-word

My Wenlin dictionary describes 身 as also a measure word for "suits of clothing".

Is it commonly used by Chinese speakers?

Comment: Yes ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 4):

身 as a classifier means 'a suits of' or "a body full of" but it usually only use '一' (one)  as counting word

Example:

他一身白色衣褲鞋帽 = He in a suits of white clothing, shoes and hat.

*他兩身白色衣褲鞋帽 is ungrammatical*

一身酒味 = a body full of alcohol smell

*兩身酒味 is ungrammatical*

Comment: It is common to use 一身衣服，两身衣服，几身衣服，etc around Beijing.

Comment: @fefe Yes, 他買了一身白衣  can be changed to  两身, 几身; I think you can only use one  when a pronoun instead of verb  precede 一身, as in  他一身白衣, cannot be changed to  他几身白衣; As for classifier  "a body full of" 一 would be the only counting word, As in "一身武器" (a body full of weapons)

Comment: Or maybe you can also use 要想俏，一身孝。

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you might see 一身正气，which means this person you wan to describe is full of sense of justice.